# How to get ellipsis in a JLabel containing HTML?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

When I combine HTML tags into the JLabel text I am loosing the ellipsis behavior that is shown when the space is too small to display the complete text. In my specific case, it is a TableCellRenderer which extends JLabel (swing's default or other). Now, when the column width is too small for the text to be shown fully, it is not showing the ellipsis.

See the image below for example:
For the left column I wrapped the text at the renderer with HTML: `setText("<html>" + "<strong>" + value.toString() + "</strong>" + "</html>");`. As you can see when the column width is too small to contain the text, it is just cut. The right column however, showing the date and time and using `DefaultTableCellRenderer` is showing ellipsis when it fails to contain the complete text.

[image]

So my question is, can I have both? Meaning, wrapping the text with HTML and still get the ellipsis?

**UPDATE:**

I found the reason for not getting the ellipsis when using HTML. I followed the code from `JComponent#paintComponent(Graphics g)` all the way down to `BasicLabelUI#layoutCL(...)`. See the following code snippet taken from the last. It is only clipping the string if it does not have the html property (which is true when the label text is wrapped with html). Yet I have no idea how to work around it:

```
    v = (c != null) ? (View) c.getClientProperty("html") : null;
    if (v != null) {
        textR.width = Math.min(availTextWidth,
                               (int) v.getPreferredSpan(View.X_AXIS));
        textR.height = (int) v.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS);
    } else {
        textR.width = SwingUtilities2.stringWidth(c, fm, text);
        lsb = SwingUtilities2.getLeftSideBearing(c, fm, text);
        if (lsb < 0) {
            // If lsb is negative, add it to the width and later
            // adjust the x location. This gives more space than is
            // actually needed.
            // This is done like this for two reasons:
            // 1. If we set the width to the actual bounds all
            //    callers would have to account for negative lsb
            //    (pref size calculations ONLY look at width of
            //    textR)
            // 2. You can do a drawString at the returned location
            //    and the text won't be clipped.
            textR.width -= lsb;
        }
        if (textR.width > availTextWidth) {
            text = SwingUtilities2.clipString(c, fm, text,
                                              availTextWidth);
            textR.width = SwingUtilities2.stringWidth(c, fm, text);
        }
        textR.height = fm.getHeight();
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: It's hard to comment without seeing specific examples, but you could create plain text for the JLabel and HTML text for a tool tip corresponding to the JLabel.

Comment: trying using `pack()`? Not 100% sure without seeing the code and trying it out but adding that after you `setText` might work.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the HTML content is simple, as in your question, the ellipsis showing can be accomplished with a custom made JLabel. Here is a working example.
Just resize the window and you see the ellipsis appear and disappear and the text cut appropriately as the label resizes with the window.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class SimpleHTMLJLabel extends JLabel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1799635451172963826L;

    private String textproper;
    private String ellipsis = "...";
    private int textproperwidth;
    private FontMetrics fontMetrics;
    private int ellipsisWidth;
    private int insetsHorizontal;
    private int borderHorizontal;

    public SimpleHTMLJLabel(String textstart, String textproper, String textend)
    {
        super(textstart + textproper + textend);
        this.textproper = textproper;
        insetsHorizontal = getInsets().left + getInsets().right;
        fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
        calculateWidths();
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
            {
                int availablewidth = getWidth();
                if (textproperwidth > availablewidth - (insetsHorizontal + borderHorizontal)) 
                {
                    String clippedtextproper = textproper;
                    while (clippedtextproper.length() > 0 
                           && fontMetrics.stringWidth(clippedtextproper) + ellipsisWidth > availablewidth - (insetsHorizontal + borderHorizontal)) 
                    {
                        clippedtextproper = clipText(clippedtextproper);
                    }
                    setText(textstart + clippedtextproper + ellipsis + textend);
                } else 
                {
                    setText(textstart + textproper + textend);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void calculateWidths()
    {
        if (textproper != null) 
        {
            textproperwidth = fontMetrics.stringWidth(textproper);
        }

        if (ellipsis != null)
        {
            ellipsisWidth = fontMetrics.stringWidth(ellipsis);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setFont(Font font)
    {
        super.setFont(font);
        fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
        calculateWidths();
    }

    private String clipText(String clippedtextproper)
    {
        return clippedtextproper.substring(0, clippedtextproper.length() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBorder(Border border)
    {
        super.setBorder(border);
        borderHorizontal = border.getBorderInsets(this).left + border.getBorderInsets(this).right;
    }
}
```

MAIN

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame window = new JFrame();
                window.setResizable(true);
                window.setTitle("Label Test");
                window.getContentPane().add(getContent());
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                window.setSize(400, 200);
                window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected static Component getContent()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        SimpleHTMLJLabel label = new SimpleHTMLJLabel("<html><strong>", "TEST1test2TEST3test4TEST5test6TEST7test8TEST", "</strong></html>");
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 5),
        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(20F));
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say: No, you can't have both.

I think if you want custom styling and ellipsis you will have to do it yourself without HTML and with a custom TableCellRenderer.

If you want to try and have your cake and eat it too, you might be able to get there by creating your own View object and setting it with c.putClientProperty("html", value) but I suspect that the HTML rendering code has no notion of ellipsing (text-overflow is an HTML 5ish feature) so you would have to figure out how to teach it to do that. I suspect this would be very difficult and much harder than just writing your own TableCellRenderer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of SimpleHTMLJLabel which is using code above

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML.Tag;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback;

public class SimpleHTMLJLabel extends JLabel {

    private static final String ellipsis = "...";
    private static final String Set = null;
    private int textproperwidth;
    private FontMetrics fontMetrics;
    private int ellipsisWidth;
    private int insetsHorizontal;
    private int borderHorizontal;

    private List<Entry<String, String>> lines;
    static String HTML = "<HTML>";

    public SimpleHTMLJLabel() {
        insetsHorizontal = getInsets().left + getInsets().right;
        fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
        calculateWidths();
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                int availablewidth = getWidth();
                renderHtml(availablewidth);
            }
        });
    }

    public SimpleHTMLJLabel(String text) {
        this();
        setText(text);
    }

    public SimpleHTMLJLabel(List<Entry<String, String>> lines) {
        this();
        this.lines = lines;
        calculateWidths();
        super.setText(HTML + toHtml(lines));
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        if (text.toUpperCase().startsWith(HTML)) {
            this.lines = parseHtml(text);
            calculateWidths();
            super.setText(HTML + toHtml(lines));
            return;
        }
        super.setText(text);
    }

    private List<Entry<String, String>> parseHtml(String text) {
        List<Entry<String, String>> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        java.util.Map<Tag, MutableAttributeSet> tags = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            (new javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator()).parse(new StringReader(text), new ParserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void handleEndTag(Tag t, int pos) {
                    //TODO clean handle MutableAttributeSet a
                    tags.remove(t);
                }

                @Override
                public void handleStartTag(javax.swing.text.html.HTML.Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos) {
                    if (t == Tag.HTML) return;
                    if (t == Tag.P) return;
                    if (t == Tag.BR) return;
                    if (t == Tag.BODY) return;
                    tags.put(t,a);
                }

                @Override
                public void handleText(char[] data, int pos) {

                    String formats = tags.entrySet().stream().map(t -> "<" + t.getKey() + getAttrib(t.getValue) + ">").collect(Collectors.joining());
                    ret.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(formats, new String(data)));
                }

                private String getAttrib(MutableAttributeSet t) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //return " style='color:red'";
                    return " " + t;
                }
            }, false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private static String toEndTag(String s) {
        return s.replace("<", "</");
    }

    private static String toHtml(List<Entry<String, String>> lines) {
        return lines.stream().map(s -> s.getKey() + s.getValue() + toEndTag(s.getKey())).collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    private static String toPlain(List<Entry<String, String>> lines) {
        return lines.stream().map(s -> s.getValue()).collect(Collectors.joining("  "));
    }

    static private List<Entry<String, String>> clipText(List<Entry<String, String>> properList) {
        Entry<String, String> last = properList.get(properList.size() - 1);
        List<Entry<String, String>> ret = properList.subList(0, properList.size() - 1);
        String newlastValue = truncate(last.getValue());
        if (newlastValue.isEmpty()) {
            return ret;
        }
        List<Entry<String, String>> retNew = new ArrayList<>();
        retNew.addAll(ret);
        retNew.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(last.getKey(), newlastValue));
        return retNew;
    }

    static private String truncate(String newlastValue) {
        newlastValue = newlastValue.substring(0, newlastValue.length() - 1);
        while (newlastValue.endsWith(" ")) {
            newlastValue = newlastValue.substring(0, newlastValue.length() - 1);
        }
        return newlastValue;
    }

    private void calculateWidths() {
        if (lines != null) {
            textproperwidth = fontMetrics.stringWidth(toPlain(lines));
        }
        ellipsisWidth = fontMetrics.stringWidth(ellipsis);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFont(Font font) {
        super.setFont(font);
        fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
        calculateWidths();
    }

    @Override
    public void setBorder(Border border) {
        super.setBorder(border);
        borderHorizontal = border.getBorderInsets(this).left + border.getBorderInsets(this).right;
    }
}
```

When using my code in TableCellRenderer you need to resize immediately in constructor time, but when you do not have a size of the column:

```
    public SimpleHTMLJLabel() {
...
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            int availablewidth = getWidth();
            renderHtml(availablewidth);
        }
    });
}

protected void renderHtml(int availablewidth) {
    if (lines == null || availablewidth == 0) return;
    System.out.println("renderHtml " + textproperwidth + ">" + availablewidth);
    if (textproperwidth > availablewidth - (insetsHorizontal + borderHorizontal)) {
        List<Entry<String, String>> properList = clipText(lines);
        while (properList.size() > 0 && fontMetrics.stringWidth(toPlain(properList)) + ellipsisWidth > availablewidth - (insetsHorizontal + borderHorizontal)) {
            properList = clipText(properList);
        }
        SimpleHTMLJLabel.super.setText(HTML + toHtml(properList) + ellipsis);
    } else {
        SimpleHTMLJLabel.super.setText(HTML + toHtml(lines));
    }
}
@Override
public void reshape(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    if (w > 0) renderHtml(w - 5);
    super.reshape(x, y, w, h);
}
```

and in JTable

```
    table = new JTable(model) {
        @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
            javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer.UIResource csss;
            SimpleHTMLJLabel lab = new SimpleHTMLJLabel(((JLabel) 
                            //lab.setXXX( c.getXXX)); for font bcolor, color, border, etc
                            lab.setText(c.getText());
            lab.renderHtml(col.getWidth() - 5);
            return lab;
        }
    };
```

One can reuse html-labell component to save GC

Comment: When using my code in TableCellRenderer yout need to resize immediattelly in constructor time, but when you do not have size of column:

Comment: when Oracle fix HTML rendering to use style='white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis' one do not neew more than just JLable or other cComponentto make "..."  as it do in popular browsers. speciellt usefull for multiline table rows and variable font size + icons etc